# How do I solve a "dyld: Library not loaded:" error in Xcode 4 unit tests?

Tags: cocoa, unit-testing, xcode4, dyld

I have an Xcode 4 project, a Cocoa application with Spotlight, Core Data and unit tests. The app uses a custom framework named TBPluginManager I wrote to load bundles. I originally wrote the framework in Xcode 3 but when I used it in Xcode 4 GDB kept complaining, so I recreated the framework in Xcode 4. This made GDB happy, until I tried to run the built-in unit-test and got:

> [Switching to process 3840 thread 0x0]
>   dyld: Library not loaded: > Library/Frameworks/TBPluginManager.framework/Versions/A/TBPluginManager
>     Referenced from: /Users/elise/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BookManager-cooglmktssmptpatjuetculukiqd/Build/Products/Release/BookManager.app/Contents/MacOS/BookManager
>
> Reason: image not found
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
>   No memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc

Now I can understand why the unit test cannot find the framework since it lives not at Library/Frameworks/TBPluginManager.framework but at /Library/Frameworks/TBPluginManager.framework. But how do I tell that to the unit-test bundle? I've tried setting the Framework, Header and Library Search path build setting, but to no avail.

BTW, I've gone back to GHUnit but I'd like to get this working as well.

FOLLOW-UP: Much as it bugs me that Grady Player got an account just to tell me that I'm an idiot, it just may be that he or she is right. My lovely, dependable framework is generating warnings and errors like they're going out of fashion and so I've turned the problem over to Apple Developer Technical Support. If anything interesting comes out of it, I'll post it here. Otherwise, I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the framework installed at /Library/Frameworks/TBPluginManager.framework is valid and the same arch as you are trying to link it to. If you are in doubt recompile the framework again, put it in a custom location and set that custom location in your framework search path.

Comment: I'm very sure the framework is where it is and is working fine. Apart from the BookManager app that I referenced in my question, several other apps also use that framework and have been doing so for more than a year now.